# How to use Apache BenchMark without a domain name?

Tags: linux, apache, ubuntu, server, benchmarking

I don't have any domain name for my server.
It is just a backend api. 
I am planning to use it with ip address.

How do i test the benchmark without domain name?

```
an -n 1000 -c -10 http://ip_address
```

is not working

Answer (score 0):

Map the IP to a server name in /etc/hosts

```
 phantom.local 10.0.0.7
```

then execute

```
ab -n 555 -c -10 http://phantom.local -
```

Comment: `ab -n 1000 -c -10 http://ip_address` -- It is wrong i have to use a trailing slash `ab -n 1000 -c -10 http://ip_address/`

Comment: np, does not change my answer ;-)